# RICH:dataTable - refresh page after delete row

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have rich datatable with delete button:

[image]

When I delete the row, row is really deleted in database, but still remains in dataTable. It dissapear after reload page or reload dataTable.

part of dataTable code:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
  value="#{myBdeCheck.dataListBde}"
  var="bdeItem">

 <rich:column width="60px">
  <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Kusy" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.prodPcs}" rendered="#{!myBdeCheck.editMode}"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{bdeItem.prodPcs}" rendered="#{myBdeCheck.editMode}"/>
 </rich:column>

 <rich:column width="50px">
  <h:commandLink action="#{myBdeCheck.deleteBde}">
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/delete.png" alt="edit"/>
    <a4j:param value="#{it.index}" assignTo="#{myBdeCheck.currentIndexDetail}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBdeCheck.BDEItem}" value="#{bdeItem}" />
  </h:commandLink>
 </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

and part of myBdeCheck bean:

```
private int currentIndexDetail; // with getters, setters
private BDE BDEItem;

public void deleteBde()
{
  try 
  { 
    DaoCrud.delete(BDEItem, 'R');
  } 
  catch{.....}
}
```

How can I make dataTable to refresh automatically after click the delete button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `rerender` the datatable after action is performed

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBdeCheck.deleteBde}" reRender="idOfYourDataTable">
```

Check [this](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit&skin=blueSky) for more info..

Comment: @gaffcz - it should work, alternatively try implementing as shown in the richfaces showcase, using `a4j:jsFunction` and `render` attribute..

Comment: @gaffcz - also check is your list `dataListBde` in session? if so are you reloading the list?

Answer (score 1):

you need to `reRender` table after deleting.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
  value="#{myBdeCheck.dataListBde}"
  var="bdeItem" id="myTable">
```

and

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBdeCheck.deleteBde}" reRender="myTable">
```